# Bibliography in document class aip-cp

Tags: document-classes

I am using the documentclass `aip-cp` but I am having the message:

`You have requested document class aip-cp,but the document class provides article.`

But the document come out nicely.

Besides, I am having problem in the bibliography. The output won't even have the section "REFERENCES".
This is my document:

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\begin{document}

\cite{menger}

\bibliographystyle{aipnum-cp}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

This is my .bib file.

```
@BOOK{menger,
   author       = {M. P. Brown and K. Austin},
   year         = {2005},
   title        = {The New Physique},
   publisher    = {Publisher Name},
   address      = {Publisher City},
   pages        = {25--30},
}
```

P/s: I downloaded the zip file from [AIP](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/info/authors)

Comment: Well, contact the maintainer about the wrong class name ;-) The other stuff is .. another question

Comment: The class starts with `\ProvidesClass{article}` instead of `\ProvidesClass{aip-cp}`; the authors/maintainers forgot to change the name. The warning is just annoying, but innocuous.

Comment: As far as the bibliography issue is concerned, did you run BibTeX?

Comment: I m new to latex. I am a bit confusing. So, what should I do with the documentclass?
    \documentclass{aip-cp}

Change it?

Comment: You should change the `article` to `aip-cp` in the `\ProvidesClass` line of the aip-cp.cls file. The line `\documentclass{aip-cp}` in your tex file is fine and should remain.

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in the document class file (`aip-cp.cls`):

```
 \ProvidesClass{article}[2014/12/10 v1.0 Standard LaTeX document class for AIP Conference Proceedings]
```

It gives a class name, which is already being used by the orginal article class. The name of the file, which you use in your document class, and the class name it 'provides' don't match up. Therefore, an error is raised. It should be:

```
 \ProvidesClass{aip-cp}[2014/12/10 v1.0 Standard LaTeX document class for AIP Conference Proceedings]
```

That problem behind the .bib loading is probably a different one.